# How can I get the AutoFac's IComponentContext from HostBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I am using HostedService with AutoFac as its container. However, .NET's IServiceProvider cannot resolve services using keys unlike AutoFac.

```
//autofac
componentContext.ResolveKeyed<ISampleService>("debug");

//not available in .NET HostBuilder even if I used autofac as container
host.Services.GetService<ISampleService>();
```

I tried getting the IComponentContext but it returns null

```
host.Services.GetService<IComponentContext>();
```

This is how I registered the services.

```
 var builder = new HostBuilder()
   .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
   .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>((context, builder) =>
   {
      builder.RegisterType<FakeDatabase>().Named<IDatabase>("debug");
      builder.RegisterType<HostedService>().Named<IHostedService>("debug");
      builder.RegisterType<ActualDatabase>().As<IDatabase>();
      builder.RegisterType<HostedService>().As<IHostedService>();
   });
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resolving an `ILifetimeScope` - that will give you the Autofac scope from which you can then resolve keyed things. Be aware that's service location and not DI, but it'll work.

Comment: Thanks :) it worked. Don't worry these are all done in Composition root. Based on commandline switch, I should be able to modify/insert some additional dependencies to capture logging output. :)